# Lenovo ThinkPad: What does the PWMDBSVC.exe service do? It's writing a C:\Log.txt file

Tags: windows, process, thinkpad, logging, services

I found a file that keeps popping up in my C:\ drive root, Log.txt ... after installing Process Monitor and seeing what process was writing to it, I came across PWMDBSVC.exe, which appears to be part of the Lenovo ThinkPad software.  Even if I delete it, I can get it to re-create the Log.txt when I lock and unlock my workstation.

Does anybody know what this software does and whether it is safe to disable?  I searched Google already and got the usual pile of useless hits on the process name but nothing seemingly definitive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to the Power Management utility, When I have to manage Lenovo machines, I personally disable the service and use [Batterycare](http://batterycare.bkspot.com/en/index.html).

So, you can disable it. Take a look at the utility first and make sure it doesn't offer anything that you really need, however, I can say that it doesn't "brake" anything by removing it.

Comment: Great thanks! I was also getting kind of worried why it kept logging stuff whenever I lock and unlock my machine. I'm going to disable it.